# Transform project to a maven project in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, jakarta-ee, maven

I have created a Dynamic Web Project in eclipse a couple of month ago and I have added many jar to the lib directory, my project is a Spring-Core/JSF/RicheFaces/Hibernate project, I plan use maven and my question is as following : what are the steps that I have to do to get a Maven project from my existant project. Thank in advance.

Comment: Content of the post updated, first answer was for old post, Thanks @sique.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Convert Existing Eclipse Project to Maven Project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project)

Answer (score 0):

Proprties -> Build Path -> Libraries

check this

Comment: Thank you, I have updated the title of my post, answers welcome.