# How to add pom.xml to existing Eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, m2e

I'm new to Maven and use Eclipse Juno. I've installed Maven Integration for Eclipse. There are three options in File > New > Other > Maven: 
1. Checkout Maven Projects from SCM
2. Maven Module
3. Maven Project 
But I don't see Maven2 POM as described [here](http://www.theserverside.com/news/1363817/Introduction-to-m2eclipse). I've read that adding pom.xml is the first thing to do when using Maven.

I have an existing Dynamic Web Project so I'm not sure whether I need to create Maven Project just to use Maven.

**How to use Maven with this existing project?**

Further, when I try to add Maven Project and on step "Select an Archetype", then all shown archetypes have version "RELEASE". When I click Next on this step, Eclipse becomes Not Responding. It's used memory doesn't even increase.

Answer (score 38, accepted):

Take a look here :

- [Convert Existing Eclipse Project to Maven Project](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project)

In last version of eclipse (Juno included), there is a more convenient wizard :

```
Configure > Convert to maven project
```

Answer (score 9):

You need to import the project as a Maven project.

```
File -> Import -> Maven -> Import existing Maven project.
```

Comment: Are you sure you installed M2E and you're not using the built in Eclipse Maven stuff? Last time I checked M2E it a separate plugin.

Comment: I have "Maven Integration for Eclipse" installed in Eclipse Marketplace.

Comment: I was wondering how to import my existing maven project into eclipse (ubuntu)... thanks @AndrewFinnell