# How do I migrate an Eclipse GAE project to Maven such that it won't be tied to Eclipse?

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I have an open source Eclipse Google App Engine project (it's called LastCalc and it's open source, you can find it [here](https://github.com/sanity/LastCalc), created using the GAE Eclipse plugin.

The problem is that several months ago I switched IDEs to IntelliJ IDEA.  Since most of my projects were Maven-based this wasn't an issue, but LastCalc was stubbornly tied to Eclipse.

I'm hoping that someone can suggest an easy way to migrate this project to Maven such that it will work nicely in both IDEA and Eclipse.

Comment: Oh, and I'll buy a beer for anyone that can do the modification themselves and submit a pull request ;-)

Comment: See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We released the [app engine maven plugin](https://developers.google.com/appengine/docs/java/tools/maven) and a [gustbook sample](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/appengine-guestbook-java) with that plugin. I don't think the manual migration is very difficult. You can create a directory structure similar to our guestbook sample and copy your source and resource files. Dependency might be a bit cumbersome, so maybe you can try the 'Convert to Maven Project' functionality of the newer version of m2eclipse.

Comment: Thank you, I've made some progress but have run into another hurdle, which I describe here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15461729/google-app-engine-maven-plugin-unable-to-start-devserver  Any advice would be appreciated.