# Google App Engine Maven plugin: Unable to start devserver

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I'm trying to migrate my Eclipse GAE project to use Maven and the Google App Engine Maven plugin instead.

Everything appears to be set up correctly, the tests all pass, however when I attempt to run the devserver I get the following output:

https://gist.github.com/sanity/5181682

You can see the source code, including my pom.xml file, here: https://github.com/sanity/LastCalc/tree/maven-conversion

Any guidance would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: which java version are you using? (java -version output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this is a Java version issue.The current plugin detects java executable by looking for ${JAVA_HOME}, where is your JAVA_HOME pointing to? See also the source:https://code.google.com/p/appengine-maven-plugin/source/browse/src/main/java/com/google/appengine/DevAppServerRunner.java

Comment: Thank you again - that was it, and my devserver now runs correctly.  Unfortunately I'm now having a problem configuring my backend, would really appreciate it if you could take a look: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15463773/unable-to-configure-new-gae-maven-plugin-back-end