# Unable to configure new GAE Maven plugin back-end

Tags: java, google-app-engine, maven

I've migrated my Eclipse GAE project to use the Maven GAE plugin.  I've now got it to the point that the devserver runs correctly (ie. mvn appengine:devserver).

However, when I attempt to try mvn appengine:backends_configure, I get the following exception: https://gist.github.com/sanity/5182601

Any ideas?

Comment: Do you have your backend configuration file? I don't see it in your repository.

Comment: Ah, that could indeed be it.  How do I create it, and where should I put it?  Alternatively, if you can direct me to the appropriate documentation I'm sure I can figure it out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try it after putting your backends.yaml in src/main/webapp/WEB-INF.

Comment: Hmm, well - I'm not really using GAE backends, should I just put an empty text file there?

Comment: Ok, wait - I think I've misundersood.  What I'm trying to do here is simply deploy my app to GAE - how do I do this?

Comment: mvn appengine:update gives me this: https://gist.github.com/sanity/5183271 - seems to be backends related even though I have no backends.yaml file, because I've got no backends :-/

Comment: Can you show me the result of the following command?
$ find target -name 'backends.*'

Comment: If you don't use backends, remove all of the backends.[yaml|xml], and run mvn appengine:update to deploy. You don't need to run mvn appengine:backends_configure.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/26353/discussion-between-takashi-matsuo-and-sanity)