# Java tool for easy dependency management in eclipse

Tags: java

Is there any tool for java that I can use to automatically download the jars for the frameworks I want to use and manage there dependencies in Eclipse. I have always admired Visual Studio and how easy it is to do stuff like that and I'm wonder if there is any capability like that for Eclipse.

Comment: maven. Maven. MAVEN!!

Comment: Weellll Eclipse itself is pretty powerful, are u sure it can't suffice? edit: Oyaa [Maven is it](http://maven.apache.org/eclipse-plugin.html)

Comment: How do you do dependency management in VS?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use Maven, along with the m2 plugin for Eclipse. It is the most common way to automatically download dependencies in the Java world.

Answer (score 1):

The best tool for dependency management is Maven. This would require you to maven-ify your eclipse project however.

With maven you specify your top-level dependency and Maven will work out what that dependency depends on.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project) is an SO question on converting an eclipse project to maven.

Answer (score 0):

You can try Ivy http://ant.apache.org/ivy/, its a bit rough start but works great.

Answer (score 0):

if you use maven as build tool

You could define the dependancies in pom.xml as below which will automatically download jars(junit-4.0.jar in this case) from specified repository on maven build.

```
<dependencies>
    <dependency>
      <groupId>junit</groupId>
      <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
      <version>4.0</version>
      <type>jar</type>
      <scope>test</scope>
      <optional>true</optional>
    </dependency>
    ...
  </dependencies>
```

Answer (score 0):

See [Apache Buildr](http://buildr.apache.org/). It's compatible with maven repositories and uses Ruby scripting language instead of tenths of XML files.

Other options is [Graddle](http://www.gradle.org/), similar to latter and Groovy-based.

Comment: By that token why not gradle?