# Getting Error injecting constructor, javax.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found

Tags: json, osgi

We're use javax.json for a while in a bundle in an osgi application. Everything worked fine with org.glassfish.javax.json 1.0.4 as the provider implementation. These days, we needed to update to 1.1.2 due to another framework we're using. Now we get the following stacktrace:

```
*com.google.inject.ProvisionException: Guice provision errors:

1) Error injecting constructor, javax.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found
  at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.GraphJSONProvider.<init>(Unknown Source)
  while locating net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.GraphJSONProvider
  while locating net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.api.IGraphJSONProvider

1 error
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:987)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.impl.DefaultResourceServiceProvider.get(DefaultResourceServiceProvider.java:74)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationRuntimeGeneratorProvider.getGraphJSONProvider(OrganizationRuntimeGeneratorProvider.java:52)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationServiceExtender$OrganizationService.<init>(OrganizationServiceExtender.java:114)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationServiceExtender$1.process(OrganizationServiceExtender.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osbp.xtext.builder.metadata.services.IUnitOfWork$GetAllUnitOfWork.exec(IUnitOfWork.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osbp.xtext.builder.metadata.services.IUnitOfWork$GetAllUnitOfWork.exec(IUnitOfWork.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osbp.xtext.builder.metadata.services.impl.MetadataBuilder$ServiceImpl.execute(MetadataBuilder.java:1349)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationServiceExtender.activate(OrganizationServiceExtender.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponent(InstanceProcess.java:620)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.InstanceProcess.buildComponents(InstanceProcess.java:197)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.buildNewlySatisfied(Resolver.java:473)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.Resolver.enableComponents(Resolver.java:217)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.startedBundle2(SCRManager.java:657)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.startedBundle(SCRManager.java:578)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.SCRManager.bundleChanged(SCRManager.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.dispatchEvent(BundleContextImpl.java:903)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:230)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.ListenerQueue.dispatchEventSynchronous(ListenerQueue.java:148)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEventPrivileged(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:213)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:120)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxEventPublisher.publishBundleEvent(EquinoxEventPublisher.java:112)
Caused by: javax.json.JsonException: Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found
    at javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:97)
    at javax.json.Json.createBuilderFactory(Json.java:282)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.GraphJSONProvider.<init>(GraphJSONProvider.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.impl.DefaultResourceServiceProvider.get(DefaultResourceServiceProvider.java:74)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationRuntimeGeneratorProvider.getGraphJSONProvider(OrganizationRuntimeGeneratorProvider.java:52)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationServiceExtender$OrganizationService.<init>(OrganizationServiceExtender.java:114)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationServiceExtender$1.process(OrganizationServiceExtender.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osbp.xtext.builder.metadata.services.IUnitOfWork$GetAllUnitOfWork.exec(IUnitOfWork.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osbp.xtext.builder.metadata.services.IUnitOfWork$GetAllUnitOfWork.exec(IUnitOfWork.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osbp.xtext.builder.metadata.services.impl.MetadataBuilder$ServiceImpl.execute(MetadataBuilder.java:1349)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationServiceExtender.activate(OrganizationServiceExtender.java:82)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponent.activate(ServiceComponent.java:235)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.activate(ServiceComponentProp.java:146)
    at org.eclipse.equinox.internal.ds.model.ServiceComponentProp.build(ServiceComponentProp.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl cannot be found by javax.json-api_1.0.0
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClassInternal(BundleLoader.java:461)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:372)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.BundleLoader.findClass(BundleLoader.java:364)
    at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.loader.ModuleClassLoader.loadClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:161)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:351)
    at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:264)
    at javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:94)
    at javax.json.Json.createBuilderFactory(Json.java:282)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.GraphJSONProvider.<init>(GraphJSONProvider.java:57)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
    at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
    at com.google.inject.internal.DefaultConstructionProxyFactory$1.newInstance(DefaultConstructionProxyFactory.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorInjector.construct(ConstructorInjector.java:85)
    at com.google.inject.internal.ConstructorBindingImpl$Factory.get(ConstructorBindingImpl.java:254)
    at com.google.inject.internal.FactoryProxy.get(FactoryProxy.java:54)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4$1.call(InjectorImpl.java:978)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.callInContext(InjectorImpl.java:1024)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl$4.get(InjectorImpl.java:974)
    at com.google.inject.internal.InjectorImpl.getInstance(InjectorImpl.java:1013)
    at org.eclipse.xtext.resource.impl.DefaultResourceServiceProvider.get(DefaultResourceServiceProvider.java:74)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationRuntimeGeneratorProvider.getGraphJSONProvider(OrganizationRuntimeGeneratorProvider.java:52)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationServiceExtender$OrganizationService.<init>(OrganizationServiceExtender.java:114)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationServiceExtender$1.process(OrganizationServiceExtender.java:75)
    at org.eclipse.osbp.xtext.builder.metadata.services.IUnitOfWork$GetAllUnitOfWork.exec(IUnitOfWork.java:112)
    at org.eclipse.osbp.xtext.builder.metadata.services.IUnitOfWork$GetAllUnitOfWork.exec(IUnitOfWork.java:1)
    at org.eclipse.osbp.xtext.builder.metadata.services.impl.MetadataBuilder$ServiceImpl.execute(MetadataBuilder.java:1349)
    at net.osbee.xtext.organizationdsl.services.OrganizationServiceExtender.activate(OrganizationServiceExtender.java:82)
*
```

The code we wrote is unchanged for years, it has been taken from the javax.json sample code.

I found [Provider org.glassfish.json.JsonProviderImpl not found at javax.json.spi.JsonProvider.provider(JsonProvider.java:97)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47022653/provider-org-glassfish-json-jsonproviderimpl-not-found-at-javax-json-spi-jsonpro), which seems to describe the same problem. I've checked my MANIFEST.MF, the javax.json-api is in the required bundles list, marked as optional.

The loaded bundles in the applications console related to json are as follows:

```
*id State       Bundle
738 RESOLVED    org.glassfish.javax.json_1.0.4
740 RESOLVED    javax.json-api_1.0.0*
```

The behavior is the same with the version 1.1.2.

This drives me nuts :(

Many thanks in advance for assistance.

Ralf

Comment: In the meantime, I was able to reproduce the old status. So, when I remove the version 1.1.2 bundles and the javax.jason-api 1.0, everything works fine.

Comment: some more information: when using version 1.0.4 and 1.1.2 in the application, org.glassfish.javax.json finds the json-api 1.1.2, because the dependency has no upper bound in the version.