# How do I create a sbt build file from a mixed java/scala eclipse project?

Tags: java, eclipse, scala, sbt

I have multiple mixed java/scala eclipse projects, with dependencies between them.
Is there a way to automatically create an sbt build file?

A little more infos about the projects:
They were started as Java projects, using libgdx with eclipse.
I added Scala and build it with the internal scala-ide sbt builder.
So its already using sbt to build. I want to use emacs with sbt, 
while my colleague wants to work with eclipse.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No. There is not.

The [same question for Maven](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project) summarize most of the problems of creating a complete build definition from Eclipse projects. Mainly the configuration of the external dependencies and between the different projects.

The common case is to go the other way around, from an sbt project to the Eclipse configuration files.
Depending of your projects you may want to create a build for each project, or one for all projects, or something in between.

Multi-projects builds are described [here](http://www.scala-sbt.org/release/docs/Getting-Started/Multi-Project.html), but I would strongly advise to read the getting started guide from the beginning.

Then, creating the Eclipse configuration files is done using the [sbteclipse plugin](https://github.com/typesafehub/sbteclipse/wiki).