# How do I mavenize a JSF 2.0 project in eclipse?

Tags: eclipse, jsf, maven, jsf-2, m2eclipse

I have a JSF 2.0 project on my eclipse.  I would like to mavenize the same preferably from Eclipse itself.  I tried doing it from outside the eclipse manually.  There are quite a few steps and I don't like the manual nature of that approach.  Could someone help?

Comment: Which are the specific problems you're facing?

Comment: See: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project

Comment: I can strongly recommend writing the pom by hand.  If you use Maven you must be familiar with the pom and how it works, especially for web projects which are rather complex.  If you want to deploy to a Java EE 6 container you can simply compile against a Glassfish set of libraries.

Comment: @ Luiggi, there are additional efforts of moving around the folder to suit maven standards.  But, as per Phantom it seems to be a manual task only.  It only makes sense, as Maven or Maven plugin for eclipse will not know which folders to be moved where anyway.  The other benefit is that this action create a pom.xml file (not big deal anyway).  @Thorbjorn, I am familiar with pom.xml file, so I prefer as automation as possible.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make sure that you have the standard folder structure as recommended by Maven for web projects.  Follow this [link](http://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html).

Now, install maven plugin in eclipse (am not sure if it is available by default or we have to download it manually).  Simply right click on the project, select Configure and Convert to Maven Project. This should automatically do all that steps to takes to mavenize your current project. This will create a pom.xml file and you can modify it going forward as per your requirements.  By the way, I use Eclipse Juno.