# Converting Eclipse project to Maven without losing structure

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

In Eclipse 4.4.2, when converting a project to maven, the IDE added a `pom.xml` and a few other things but the project structure remained unchanged. Is this standard behavior?

I was expecting it to be updated to the *maven structure*. The conversion was done by right-click on the project and then in the context menu Maven->Convert. (Is there a trick, some other option, to make it *adjust* the project structure to be maven-like?)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure but i believe that's the standard behavior, of course you'd have to add the maven dependencies and the rest of your jars right after.
Check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10122316/4422074) answer, about mavenizing your whole eclipse workspace, though i have *not* tested it yet.
Hope i helped

P.S possible duplicate to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project/) ?