# How do i update maven project in eclipse?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have created maven project in interactive mode using

```
    mvn archetype:generate
```

used Quick one. It creates default App.java I just modified the class as follows

```
    String greeting;
    public App(String msg)
    {
     greeting = msg;
    }

    public String getMessage()
    {   
      return greeting;
    }
```

And `mvn compile` and then `mvn eclipse:eclipse` and imported maven project as follows `file->new->maven->existing maven project->selected sample` sample contains the project.

But local has target directory with classes but eclipse has empty target directory. I just tried `alt+f5`

It has `src` folder, `maven dependencies` and `empty target`

Why target is empty here?

Any suggestions?

Comment: instead of using mvn eclipse:eclipse, just import the projects as Maven projects. This gives the projects the maven nature and enables alt+f5.

Comment: Using `mvn ecllipse:eclipse` enables you to import them as regular eclipse projects, not maven projects, but it is better to import them as maven projects without thar command.

Comment: And you have to build the project to get the artifact in the target folder. Run the project build with the goal `package`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't use `mvn eclipse:eclipse`. Eclipse has had support for importing Maven projects for a while now.

Instead, once you've generated your project from an archetype, use Eclipse's "Import > Maven > Existing Maven Project" option.

Comment: ok. I have enabled eclipse nature. Is there any other way to disable that?

Comment: Not sure what you mean. Can you edit your question with more details?

Comment: hi, Added comment to the above answer.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use eclipse IDE only. The better to create new project in eclipse itself and please follow the [URL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project).

and

To disable eclipse nature : Right click project --> Maven --> Disable maven nature

Comment: I don't think OP wants to get rid of Maven, he wants Eclipse to properly handle his Maven project.

Comment: ok. My doubt is, I have just run `maven archetype:generate` and created a sample project and imported my project in eclipse as maven project. But target folder is empty but it is not empty in local

Comment: Yes Tom, for the same thing I am trying to help him.

Comment: Gops, please try to run "mvn clean install" then refresh your project in eclipse.

Comment: Gops, I am assuming you are running this command in project home and by default it creates target directory in project home itself. If you want to specify the location to generate war, you will have to modify pom.. Something like : <configuration>
     <warName>testWar</warName>
     <outputDirectory>${CATALINA_HOME}\webapps</outputDirectory>
    </configuration>

Answer (score 0):

Before import the project into eclipse after executing "**mvn eclipse:eclipse**" command also execute the below command

```
mvn install
```

If you already imported the project into eclipse then execute the  **mvn install** command from command prompt and then **refresh the project** in eclipse. Hopefully your issue will be resolved.