# Add Maven nature to existing Eclipse project that has pom but no Maven submenu

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

How can I convert a project to Maven nature when there is no sub-menu for Maven on right click in Eclipse? The project already has a POM file.

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/q/2449461/2670892

Comment: @greg I found that question while I was initially looking for a solution, but that is for a project that does not already use Maven as its build tool it looks like.

Answer (score 33, accepted):

Right click on the project- Configure - Convert -Convert to Maven Project

This is also a method to refresh the Maven Dependencies.

Answer (score 5):

Delete the project (but do *not* delete it from disk) and re-import but choose to import an existing Maven project.

Comment: This helped me when a multi-module maven project "lost" its maven nature.

Answer (score 2):

In the latest IDE's it is this way:
right click on project >> Configure >> Convert to Maven Project

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue. I do not even have the configure option as mentioned in the accepted answer. But as @captain said i deleted them, But importing as maven doesn't work either. So I tried the other option below.

Instead of  importing as Existing maven project I imported them as `General -> Projects from folder or Archive`.

This brought back maven nature and boot nature as well.