# Directory structure after converting a project to maven in eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

I have a java project, which i converted to maven using m2e from within eclipse. Since my project was a legacy project, it was not following maven directory structure such as src/main/java and src/test/java, so after the conversion the previous directory structure didnt change.

I am wondering if there is an easy way or shortcut within m2eclipse to refactor my project to the default directory structure used by maven.

I tried adding a new source folder in my src folder and nest the folders to have src/main/java but I am getting the below error.

Please see the snapshot as i dont have enough reputation to post it.

[Snapshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vXOex.png)

Answer (score 11):

The error message is pointing out the problem - you can't nest source folders, as the package names would make no sense. It is easily fixed:

- Right click the project and select Properties
- Select **Java Build Path/Source**
- Delete all entries
- Add the standard Maven paths (src/main/java, src/main/resources, /src/test/java and src/test/resources)

Exit the Properties dialog and a Project/clean should compile everything correctly.

Comment: Cant thank you enough! Too bad i cant upvote your answer, as i dont have the required reputation.

Comment: @Saad You can probably accept this as the answer - its a long time since I had no reputation, so maybe you cant.