# Can I convert Eclipse Project to maven using command line?

Tags: java, eclipse, maven

The issue I have is that I have to work in an Eclipse version that doesn't allow any additional Plugins and hence, installing maven is not an option.

However, I am wondering whether I can still use command line to create my maven project.

If I create a maven project from command line, Eclipse -> File -> Import didn't work.
I tried to create my maven project inside eclipse project folders and I got a maven folder structure inside my original eclipse project.
Using the eclipse IDE I renamed the src folder and instead called the Maven created structure 'src'. That created a mess because I cannot create packages instead these folders.

Best Regards,

Comment: Why did you rename `src`? `src` is the standard name used in a Maven [Standard Directory Layout](https://maven.apache.org/guides/introduction/introduction-to-the-standard-directory-layout.html). Just create a "Maven Project" in Eclipse and keep the default directory structure.

Comment: Any updates on this front?

Answer (score 0):

[The M2e plugin Eclipse](http://www.eclipse.org/m2e/) is strongly recommended to work on a Maven project in Eclipse.
If you have network constraints to install it from classic Eclipse plugin installation, you may still install it by building [the source code of the plugin](https://github.com/eclipse/m2e-core).

As an alternative, you could use the [Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-eclipse-plugin/) that relies on Maven only and not Eclipse. Using it allows to generate Eclipse classpath according to the pom dependencies.
Particularly : `mvn eclipse:eclipse` that generates the Eclipse configuration files.

> The Maven Eclipse Plugin is used to generate Eclipse IDE files
>   (*.classpath, *.project, *.wtpmodules and the .settings folder) for
>   use with a project.

But it is deprecated and is not maintained any longer.
So I cannot recommend it.

> Disclaimer: Users are advised to use m2e, the Eclipse Maven
>   Integration instead of this plugin, as it can more closely resemble
>   the actual build and runtime classpaths as described in the project
>   pom.xml - among other advantages. However, there are project setups
>   and workflows that still work more efficiently with statically
>   generated Eclipse metadata - for example when there is a large number
>   of projects in a reactor. That's where the Maven Eclipse Plugin can
>   still help you.

Comment: Apache Maven Eclipse Plugin is a command line way but not recommended.

Comment: is not possible to just add a home cooked pom.xml to the project root and run maven clean install?

Comment: @Jack Flamp It is and it may build successfully. But in Eclipse, classes could not compile because of classpath issues : dependencies of the pom are not resolved. So you work with an IDE that spots errors everywhere. Not really fine.

Comment: what about mvn eclipse:eclipse?

Comment: It will overwrite Eclipse metadata to provide a classpath with all required dependencies defined in the pom.

Comment: sounds good :) I'll have to test that to see if it is a problem.

Answer (score -1):

Which version of Eclipse you are using ? You can apply plugin. Also, make sure your proxy should not block the eclipse to download the plugins. For proxy settings, refer setting.xml in conf folder of maven.