# Cannot resolve symbol BeanPropertyRowMapper

Tags: java, mapping, row, symbols

I have code below

```
  List<Tbl> list = temp.query("select * from tbl WHERE DDMM = " + ddmm.format(date), new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Tbl>(Tbl.class));
```

Error

```
error: cannot find symbol
            List<Tbl> list = temp.query("select * from tbl WHERE DDMM = " + ddmm.format(date), new BeanPropertyRowMapper<Tbl>(Tbl.class));
  symbol:   class BeanPropertyRowMapper
```

Comment: Do you have an associated `pom.xml` and can you also post the import statements you used to import `BeanPropertyRowMapper`?

Comment: @JustinAlbano I don't have any import for `BeanPropertyRowMapper`

Comment: @JustinAlbano I don't have pom.xml as well

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`BeanPropertyRowMapper` requires the `spring-jdbc` JAR to be present on the classpath. To do this, you would either need to compile your program and manually include the `spring-jdbc` JAR on the classpath using command line flags. For more information, see [Including jars in classpath on commandline (javac or apt)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2096283/including-jars-in-classpath-on-commandline-javac-or-apt). The `spring-jdbc` JAR can be found at [Maven Repository](https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc). The catch is that JAR may require many more dependencies, which can be a hassle to get right.

I would suggest turning your project into a Maven project. For more information on creating a Maven project, see [Maven in 5 Minutes](http://maven.apache.org/guides/getting-started/maven-in-five-minutes.html). Once you Mavenize your project, add the following to your `pom.xml`, where `${spring.version}` is the version of Spring you decide to use:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-jdbc</artifactId>
    <version>${spring.version}</version>
</dependency>
```

Then, in the file that uses `BeanPropertyRowMapper`, add the following import statement:

```
import org.springframework.jdbc.core.BeanPropertyRowMapper;
```

Comment: where can I get the jar file ?

Comment: The JAR can be found at https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.springframework/spring-jdbc. You have to select version and on the page for that version, there is a line in the table called **Files**. Click the **JAR** link to download the JAR for that version. For example, the link for the `4.3.15.RELEASE` version is http://central.maven.org/maven2/org/springframework/spring-jdbc/4.3.15.RELEASE/spring-jdbc-4.3.15.RELEASE.jar. Again, I would highly suggest Mavenizing your project. Trying to manually do this is often called *dependency hell*--for good reason.

Comment: Caused by: org.springframework.beans.BeanInstantiationException: Could not instantiate bean class [org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalContainerEntityManagerFactoryBean]: Constructor threw exception; nested exception is java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/NonTransientDataAccessException
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/dao/NonTransientDataAccessException

Comment: That is an indication that the `spring-jdbc` JAR requires another JAR to be on the classpath. If you look on the Maven Repository page for the `spring-jdbc` JAR (after you select a version), there is a section called **Compile Dependencies** that enumerates all of the compile-time dependencies for that JAR. **Again, I *highly* suggest you use some dependency management tool, like Maven or Gradle, to handle dependency resolution for you.** Doing it manually will be very painstaking.

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion, I can't use Maven because this project was written by someone which was 10 years ago

Comment: Not sure if this is an option, but I'll put it on the table: Can you take the existing code and put it within a Maven project structure. I.e. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2449461/convert-existing-eclipse-project-to-maven-project. If not, there are sometimes what are called *fat JARs* that contain other JARs. You may be able to find a fat JAR for Spring (which contains the dependencies as well) and try compiling with that. Past that, you may have to just download the required JARs until the `NoClassDefFoundError`s stop and you successfully compile.

Comment: I have removed the jar but still getting the same error message >< !!!!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/168458/discussion-between-justin-albano-and-john-joe).